# How to migrate an image file from SQL Server varbinary(max) to S3 .jpg or .bmp with only AWS Lambda .Net Core

Tags: c#, sql-server, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda

I am attempting to migrate image data from a SQL Server `VARBINARY(MAX)` column into AWS S3 as a *.jpg* via an AWS Lambda function using C#. Is this possible and how? (I have run into several dead-ends)

I am having trouble actually converting the data from the `VARBINARY` datatype into something standard.

- Using C# AWS Lambda
- No System.Drawing.Bitmap library to convert to
- No System.Drawing.Image library to write the binary into
- No local file system to write the binary into a file

Supposedly it should be able to convert to base 64 and save as .jpg but that is only giving me a corrupted image.

```
Byte[] raw = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("0xFFD8FFE000104A4649460001010...");
string raw64 = Convert.ToBase64String(raw);

PutObjectRequest putObj = new PutObjectRequest
{
     BucketName = input.TempBucket,
     ContentBody = raw64,
     ContentType = "image/jpg",
     Key = "uploadtest.jpg"                  
};

PutObjectResponse putResp = S3Client.PutObjectAsync(putObj).Result;
```

I can see the files uploaded to the S3 bucket.

I can't display them, always a malformed image.

Comment: What format are the images in at the moment?

Comment: its a .jpg that has been base 64 encoded